# Java 7 - How to get the 4th tuesday of may?

Tags: java, java-7

I manage to do it easlily in java 8:

```
public static Date getFourthTuesdayOfMay(int year){
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, Month.MAY, 1);
        LocalDate fourthTuesdayOfMay = date.with(dayOfWeekInMonth(4, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY));
        return Date.from(fourthTuesdayOfMay.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
```

The problem is I need to do it in **java 7** ... but can't figure out how.

Answer is:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance ();
        date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.TUESDAY);
        date.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
        date.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 4);
        date.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return date.getTime();
```

Comment: If you use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, you won't have to change your code much at all.

Comment: @4castle Or [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)

Comment: You could iterate from the start of the month to the first Tuesday, then add 21 days, but it's going to be much easier to use a library as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In java 7 one needs to use Calendar for a pure Java SE solution.
(Joda being almost java 8.)

```
public static Date getFourthTuesdayOfMay(int year) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int monthDay = 1;
    calendar.set(year, Calendar.MAY, monthDay);
    while (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.TUESDAY) {
        ++monthDay;
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, monthDay);
    }
    // monthDay = 1, ..., 7
    monthDay += 3 * 7; // At most 28 <= 31
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, monthDay);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

As the locale is not specified, one could get a non-Gregorian calendar, so maybe add Locale.FRANCE to getInstance. The loop for day-of-week could be prevented by modulo 7 but that is not as readable.

Comment: You don't clear time of day. Also, it seems a bit excessive, doing all those `get` and `set` calls in a loop, when it can be done like this: `calendar.set(year, Calendar.MAY, 1); calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (Calendar.TUESDAY + 7 - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) % 7 + 21);`, but I guess "readable" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Andreas valuable comment; I prefer the more  functional and terse style too in my code. But it is harder to comment. And negative modulo (+7) and such. Thanks for  the shorter version.